# MongoDB : Get documents whose length of array >= 2

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Asking for help to fix this mongoDb/mongoose query. It should do :

- evaluate the quantity of array elements of 'host'
- return only documents that have more than 2 elements into array
- finally, the query should get back all documents/objects of DB with ALL FIELDS following the paraments above.

**Sample Document :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXXXXXX"),
    "content" : "ASdkJAHKDA",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-01-24T17:20:00.023Z"),
    "sentEmail" : {
        "host" : [ 
            "smtp.XXX", 
            "smtp.YYYY", 
        ],
        "status" : false,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-01-27T14:36:08.311Z",
}
```

**Attempt 1 :**

```
db.getCollection('emails').find({'sentEmail.status': false}, {$where:'sentEmail.host >= 2'})
```

**Problem :** It is not return ALL fields, it returns only ID

**Attempt 2 :**

```
db.getCollection('emails').find({'sentEmail.host.1': {$exists:true}, 'sentEmail.status': false})
```

**Problem :** It returns only the first object found.

Comment: Please translate it to English to get an answer!!

Comment: @srinivasy done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
db.getCollection('emails').find({$expr :{$and : [{$eq :['$sentEmail.status', false]},
                                            {$gte: [{$size:'$sentEmail.host'},2]}]}})
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f26ead02e05b6948bc302"),
    "content" : "ASdkJAHKDA",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-01-24T17:20:00.023Z"),
    "sentEmail" : {
        "host" : [ 
            "smtp.XXX", 
            "smtp.YYYY"
        ],
        "status" : false,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-01-27T14:36:08.311Z")
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f26f1d02e05b6948bc3b5"),
    "content" : "ASdkJAHKDA",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-01-24T17:20:00.023Z"),
    "sentEmail" : {
        "host" : [ 
            "smtp.YYYY"
        ],
        "status" : false,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-01-27T14:36:08.311Z")
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f26ffd02e05b6948bc4c8"),
    "content" : "ASdkJAHKDA",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-01-24T17:20:00.023Z"),
    "sentEmail" : {
        "host" : [ 
            "smtp.XXX", 
            "smtp.YYYY", 
            "smtp.ZZZZ"
        ],
        "status" : false,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-01-27T14:36:08.311Z")
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f2bd2d02e05b6948c2c58"),
    "content" : "ASdkJAHKDA",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-01-24T17:20:00.023Z"),
    "sentEmail" : {
        "host" : [ 
            "smtp.XXX", 
            "smtp.YYYY", 
            "smtp.ZZZZ"
        ],
        "status" : true,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-01-27T14:36:08.311Z")
    }
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f26ead02e05b6948bc302"),
    "content" : "ASdkJAHKDA",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-01-24T17:20:00.023Z"),
    "sentEmail" : {
        "host" : [ 
            "smtp.XXX", 
            "smtp.YYYY"
        ],
        "status" : false,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-01-27T14:36:08.311Z")
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f26ffd02e05b6948bc4c8"),
    "content" : "ASdkJAHKDA",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-01-24T17:20:00.023Z"),
    "sentEmail" : {
        "host" : [ 
            "smtp.XXX", 
            "smtp.YYYY", 
            "smtp.ZZZZ"
        ],
        "status" : false,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-01-27T14:36:08.311Z")
    }
}
```

If did not return document with `"_id" : ObjectId("5e2f26f1d02e05b6948bc3b5")` because size of `sentEmail.host < 2` && `"_id" : ObjectId("5e2f2bd2d02e05b6948c2c58")` is not returned cause it has `sentEmail.status: true`.

Comment: Great! but you missed the sentEmail.status : false. I need that condition too. Could you help with it?

Comment: Awsome! Tks a lot